Does EditorConfig has a rule to recognize Todo Comments?
I am working on a C# .NET Code Base, where a Custom Roslyn Analyzer is involved that analyze Existence of Todo Comments. We work with the IDE JetBrains Rider 2024.2.4.
Recently we integrated EditorConfig to maintain a consistent Coding Style and asked ourself if it's possible to use a predefined rule, that detects such Todo Comments in Context of EditorConfig? With the ulterior motive of replacing the mentioned Custom Roslyn Analyzer.

Do you have a special comment rule? you could detect patterns and look for Todo-Comments with the editor. To clarify Rider has File > Settings > Editor > TODO where you could setup a pattern that looks for it

The EditorConfig wiki says there is no such option:
EditorConfig properties
The EditorConfig is more about keeping a base file handling configuration across all code editors, it is not meant for high-level convenience features.
JetBrains Rider can already list your TODO comments. You can even define a custom TODO pattern if your pattern for that differs from TODO:
Configuring TODO patterns
Beyond that, notice that StackOverflow is not for recommending plugins, extensions, libraries, etc.. because answers of that nature tend to age poorly. If you need a better handling of ToDo comments, find a general discussion forum for developers or even just google a list of todo plugins for your IDE and decide in your team what fits your requirements.
